# Handle a method return

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

In my project I will use a process method in the handle method and based on the return type that will be boolean I will have to notify the advice success for true or failure for false.

Can someone please let me know how that could be done in the integration flow? is there any other implementation probably.

Code:

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory())
                            .preserveTimestamp(true)
                            .remoteDirectory(appProperties.getFtp().getRemoteDirectory())
                            .patternFilter(appProperties.getFtp().getFilter())
                            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                            .localDirectory(new File("inbound"))
                            .temporaryFileSuffix(appProperties.getFtp().getTemporaryFileSuffix()),
                    e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter")
                            .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(appProperties.getFtp().getPollerDelay()))
                            .autoStartup(true))
            .transform(new FileToByteArrayTransformer())
            .<byte[]>handle((p, h) -> {
                log.info("After transform " + p);
                log.info("Headers " + h);
                CustomerFile customerFile = CustomerFile.builder()
                        .content(p)
                        .customerFileType(CustomerFileType.ORDER_BOOK)
                        .filename(appProperties.ftp.getFileName())
                        .build();
                customerFileDataService.save(customerFile);
                boolean isProssed = orderBookFileProcessor.process(customerFile);
                log.info("is Processed : " + isProssed);
                return isProssed;
            })
            .route(Boolean.class, p -> p.equals(false) ? "historyChannel" : "errorChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow history(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("historyChannel")
            .transform("genericMessage.headers['file_originalFile']")
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .remoteDirectory("/ftp/ge/inbound/history"))
                    .get();
}
```

error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: genericMessage.headers['file_originalFile']; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'genericMessage' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage' - maybe not public or not valid?, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=false, headers={file_remoteHostPort=bey-notes-fs.bey.ei:21, file_name=OA_ex_PK_2020_2023.csv, file_remoteDirectory=//ftp/GE/Inbound, file_originalFile=inbound\OA_ex_PK_2020_2023.csv, id=3a6ecf72-e9cd-43e6-bf0c-25020c0ab30d, file_relativePath=OA_ex_PK_2020_2023.csv, file_remoteFile=OA_ex_PK_2020_2023.csv, timestamp=1640030927539}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to take a look to different `handle()` variant:

```
/**
 * Populate a {@link ServiceActivatingHandler} for the
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor}
 * to invoke the provided {@link GenericHandler} at runtime.
 * Typically used with a Java 8 Lambda expression:
 * <pre class="code">
 * {@code
 *  .<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p / 2)
 * }
 * </pre>
 * Use {@link #handle(Class, GenericHandler)} if you need to access the entire
 * message.
 * @param handler the handler to invoke.
 * @param <P> the payload type to expect.
 * @return the current {@link IntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 * @see org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor
 */
public <P> B handle(GenericHandler<P> handler) {
```

The one you have chosen comes with plain `void handle(Message<?>)` contract. So, no any return are expected from this call. Since you have a result from the `process()` method call and you want to process it, then you need to change your flow behavior from the *consumer* to *function* at this point:

```
     .<byte[]>handle( (p, h) -> {
                log.info("After transform " + p);
                CustomerFile customerFile = CustomerFile.builder()
                        .content(p)
                        .customerFileType(CustomerFileType.ORDER_BOOK)
                        .build();
                customerFileService.saveCustomerFile(customerFile);
                return orderBookFileProcessor.process(customerFile); 
            })
```

Comment: so after returning the method true or false then I would need to tell the advice if success or failure , how that should be handled or any other suggestion? basically if it is false then it will be an failure and then will have to send the ftp file to error folder else success to history folder , edited my code@Artem Bilan

Comment: We don't know what is your `expressionAdvice()`, but what you are explaining fully fits to the router pattern: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#messaging-routing-chapter

Comment: I have edited my code to show the advice so at the time being it deletes the file from my folder when successful and just shows payload was bad when failure , basically I would create success bean that is an integration flow and will handle the file then outbounds it to the history folder else another method that is failure and routes it to the error folder, but since you are saying that my explanation falls under routing pattern , i will check the link but is there any DSL example I can quickly refer too? @Artem Bilan

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers. Also it doesn't look like you understood how to use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`. You have to throw an exception if you want that `onFailureExpression` to be evaluated. Just returning `true/false` has nothing to do with error handling.

Comment: so using the route after returning the output of the method in the handle I want to basically pass the file based on true or false to the respective channels , the file is showing in the header but giving me the error, I edited my code above @Artem Bilan

Comment: The exception is clear enough: there is no `genericMessage` property on the evaluation context root object. That object is indeed a `GenericMessage` type and it has `headers` and `payload` property. So, you expression must be simpler: `headers['file_originalFile']` or even `headers.file_originalFile` because there is a `MapAccessor` in the SpEL for `Map` type.

Comment: @ArtemBilan How I can register a `GenericHandler` in test environment? should I register to the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` that I use to trigger the flow?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I can register a `messageHandler` to a `SubscribableChannel` easily, but how should I register a `GenericHandler` ? should I register it to the channel or somewhere else?

Comment: @Sajad, I believe your question deserves its own SO thread. Please, consider to ask it separately: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ArtemBilan Yes, I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76721587/register-a-generic-handler-in-sourcepollingchanneladapter