# Register a generic handler in SourcePollingChannelAdapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-test

I have a simple integration flow and I'm using `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` for integration testing.

This is the flow:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<LatestBook> booksSource() {
    return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(booksService.getBook()).build();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow syncBooks(Trigger trigger) {
    return IntegrationFlow
            .from(booksSource(), c -> c.poller(Pollers.trigger(trigger))
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .id(BOOKS_POLLING_ADAPTER_ID))
            .handle(new BooksHandler(booksRepository))
            .channel(syncBooksMessageChannel())
            .get();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier(SYNC_BOOKS_MESSAGE_CHANNEL)
public MessageChannel syncBooksMessageChannel(){
    return Kafka.channel(kafkaTemplate, containerFactory, kafkaTemplate.getDefaultTopic())
            .id(SYNC_BOOKS_MESSAGE_CHANNEL).get();
}

... // Other flows
```

And this is the test environment:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(BOOKS_POLLING_ADAPTER_ID)
protected SourcePollingChannelAdapter booksPollingSource;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(SYNC_BOOKS_MESSAGE_CHANNEL)
private SubscribableChannel syncBooksMessageChannel;

@Autowired
private BooksHandler booksHandler;

@Test
public void testBooks() {
    booksPollingSource.setOutputChannel(syncBooksMessageChannel);
    booksPollingSource.setAutoStartup(false);

    // booksPollingSource.addHandler(booksHandler); need something like this

    booksPollingSource.start();
}
```

I can indicate the `OutputChannel` and `AutoStartup` of the `booksPollingSource` simply, but how I can tell `booksPollingSource` to use `BooksHandler` before writing to the `syncBooksMessageChannel`.

Currently, the `BooksHandler` is not triggered, and I can see un-handled messages in the kafka channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to looks into a `MockIntegration` framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing-mocks.

The point is that `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` produces messages from its source to the provided channel. The handler is a subscriber to that channel on the other side. Both of them don't know about each other. That's the whole point of Messaging - to have your solution as loosely coupled as possible.

I'm not sure what is your logic, but for now you are fully bypassing the flow you show with that `setOutputChannel(syncBooksMessageChannel)`. Meaning that indeed a message produced from source goes to the Kafka topic. If you explain a bit more your requirements, we can come up with a testing ideas for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, In `BooksHandler` I return a new type that should be written to the Kafka topic finally, but because the handler is not called, I saw the raw message goes to the Kafka topic. (I've added the `source` as well)

Comment: When I don't explicitly set the output channel, I get this error:

`Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'books-app.syncBooks.channel#0'`

Comment: Probably your `syncBooks` flow is not started. The `.handle(new BooksHandler(booksRepository))` does a subscription to that channel, but you might noe share the whole story on the matter yet: the code you show doesn't say that you have the flow stopped.